# From value and key , How to fetch the key and do the multiplication of price and Quantity?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-6

When I select the category then it is shown price on select box but when i put the value in quantity's box then it is multiply of price's value and quantity and show the total but the in which when total is come then it is fetch the id of price and quantity multiply from the id..
I want the multiplication of quantity and price not the value of price..then how i can???

Javascript for select price value from subcategories

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // now change price..........
     $(document).ready(function() 
     {    
         $('select#subcategory').on('change', function() {
            if(subID = $(this).val()) 
            {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "{{url('/')}}" + '/Purchaser/add_purchaser/ajax/' + subID,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                             $('select#productprice').empty();
                             $.each(data, function(key, value)
                             {
                                   var option = new Option(value, key);
                                   $(option).html(value);
                                   // $(option).html(value);
                                   $('select#productprice').append(option);
                             });
                        }
                    });
            }else{
                $('select#productprice').empty();
            }
         });
    }); 
    </script>
```

javascript for get total

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('tbody').delegate('#price,#quantity','keyup',function(){
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var price = tr.find('#productprice').val();
  var quantity = tr.find('#quantity').val();
  var total = (price * quantity);
  tr.find('#total').val(total);
});
</script>
```

Html file

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select class="form-control" name="cat_id[]" id="category">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                @foreach($category as $key)
                    <option value="{{ $key->id }}">{{ $key->cat_nm }}</option>
                @endforeach
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="sub_cat_id[]">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Subcategory from category</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
       <select class="form-control" id="productprice" name="price_id[]">  
           <option>Price from subcategory</option>                                     
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" id="quantity">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total[]" id="total">
       </td>
       <td>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the var price = $( "#productprice option:selected" ).text(); insted of var price = tr.find('#productprice').val(); like below script....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('tbody').delegate('#price,#quantity','keyup',function(){
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var price = $( "#productprice option:selected" ).text();
        // var price = tr.find('#productprice').val();
        var quantity = tr.find('#quantity').val();
        var total = (price * quantity);
        tr.find('#total').val(total);
      });
</script>
```